# Vitalli's theorem in proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading this short paper about the properties of additive functions and the following proof is given:

> **Theorem.** If $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable, additive function, then $f$ is linear.
>
> *Proof.* Choose $R>0$ so that $\{x:\ |f(x)|\leq R\}$ has positive Lebesgue measure. Then, Vitalli guarantees that there is a $\delta>0$ such that
> $$[-\delta,\delta]\subseteq\{y-x:\ |f(x)|\vee|f(y)|\leq R\}.$$
> Hence, $|f(x)|\leq2R$ if $|x|\leq\delta$. Given any $x\ne0$, choose $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ so that $\frac{|x|}{\delta}\leq q\leq\frac{2|x|}{\delta}$. Then $x'\equiv\frac{x}{q}\in[-\delta,\delta]$ and so $|f(x)|=q|f(x')|\leq\frac{4R|x|}{\delta}$. More generally, $|f(y)-f(x)|=|f(y-x)|\leq\frac{4R|y-x|}{\delta}$, and so $f$ is continuous. $\quad\square$

I don't understand what exactly the sentence "Then, Vitalli guarantees..." means. What theorem of his is author referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure whether they mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma) (*Vitalli* is a misspelling, unless there's a Vitalli I'm unaware of) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) - at first glance, both seem suitable - but it's important you *not* think it meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: Okay one more thing I don't understand is why proving the continuity gives us the desired linearity of function?

Comment: If you have an additive function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then it is easy to show using some induction arguments that it is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear. If it is furthermore continuous it then has to be $\mathbb{R}$-linear as well since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.